# Cumulative sum of pca explained variance greater than 1

Tags: pca, python

I am getting strange result.

data_scaled = StandardScaler().fit_transform(dat_final)

pca = PCA(.99)
pca.fit(data_scaled)

print(np.cumsum((pca.explained_variance_)))
plt.plot(np.cumsum((pca.explained_variance_)))

result I am getting is 
[ 2.9391298   5.75291849  7.18909411  8.39200852  9.22317861  9.89984402
 10.46682293 11.0008235  11.40999925 11.73238142 11.97820388]

how can the explained variance can be more than 1.

Please correct if I am wrong here. [image]

Comment: It is quite possible if the total variance in the data is larger than 1. Perhaps you were thinking of the *proportion* of explained variance instead?

Comment: I am voting to leave this open. It's not really about R - similar issues could occur with the output of any software for PCA.

Answer (score 4):

This is correct. Remember that the total variance can be more than 1! I think you are getting this confused with the fraction of total variance. Try replacing `explained_variance_` with `explained_variance_ratio_` and it should work for you. 
ie.

```
print(np.cumsum((pca.explained_variance_ratio_))
```